# android studio 2.3.3 match_parent issue

Tags: android

I`m using android studio 2.3.3 . i have problem with match parent . 
I set my layouts or text or .... height and width to match parent but android studio change it automatically to something else . I have tried old version but they were good . I have this problem with 2.3 versions.
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0f5g.jpg)

you can see in picture , I change the width and height to match parent but ....

Comment: Its result of `Constraint Layout`. Change it to `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Go to your layout xml file in edit mode(not in design), search for root element. It must be ConstraintLayout, change it to either RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

Comment: problem solved , thank you

Comment: You should read about Layouts first especially Contraint Layout which is new in 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

You may be using ConstraintLayout in xml.

It is not a bug, it's expected behaviour. Android Studio 2.3.3 support ConstraintLayout .You can find more about ConstraintLayout [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html) to know more about whats new in Android Studio 2.3.3.